# I have two sets, each increasing at a certain constant rate. I need to find x given y

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following sets:

```
x | 6 |  8 |  10 |  12 |  14 ...  
y | 4 |  5 |  6  |  7  |  8  ...
```

I need to find the value of y given any positive value of x.

I know it sounds simple, but I seem to have drawn a complete blank on this one :/

Cheers

Comment: The relation is x = 2y-2 or y = x/2 + 1

Comment: This is most certainly unfitting to the set theory tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ... means you increase x by 2 each step and y by 1, then $x=2y-2$ and $y=x/2+1$

Comment: $y = x/2 + 1$ isn't it?

Comment: Moron that's the ticket, guess I'm the moron this time :).